# Collision Detection hitTestObject not working.. ish

Tags: actionscript-3

Obviously as you can see from this clip  below, the Hit and Miss is not corresponding to the actual event on the stage. why? It works only if I give the objects instance name, but not working when using the var name. why?

here's the code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
var gball: SmallGreenBall1_T = new SmallGreenBall1_T();
var bucket: allBuckets = new allBuckets();
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)
function handleCollision(evt: Event): void {
  if (gball.hitTestObject(bucket)) {
  output_txt.text = "HIT"
  } else {
  output_txt.text = "MISS"
  }
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rL4N5Abokf0[Hit and Miss is not corresponding to the actual event on the stage][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Rookie mistake, I needed to addChild the object not preposition them on stage.